# play/stop music in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So I am attempting to play a song and then when another song or the same songs button is pressed again I want to stop whats currently playing and play the new song.

BTW, I obviously didn't post all the code in here so ignore the variables going into the music method

Here's my code:

```
global music
def music(layout, list, xs, ys, xp, yp):
    layout.buttons=[]
    for song in list:
        button=Button(text=song, size_hint=(xs, ys), pos_hint={'x':xp, 'y':yp})
        button.bind(on_press=play)
        layout.buttons.append(button)
        layout.add_widget(button)

global play
def play(button):
    song = (button.text)
    try:
        songp.stop()
        print('stop')
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        path = (str(os.getcwd()) + '/Music/' + song + '.mp3')
        songp = SoundLoader.load(str(path))
        songp.play()
```

The songs just stack

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Also, `songp.stop` should be `songp.stop()`.

Comment: No sir, I should've mentioned this in my post but the music just stacks

Comment: even when adding () it still stacks

Comment: Probably has to do with the scope of the variable `songp`. It is local to the `play()` method, so it is not valid for different executions of the `play()` method.

Comment: So what do you recommend that I do?

Comment: Try putting a line: `songp = None` before the `def play()` line.

Comment: My code doesn't read ```songp = None``` if it is placed before ```def play()```

Comment: Leave the `songp = None` before the `def play()`, but add `global songp` inside the `play()` method.

Comment: You're a life saver, Thanks!